# Calculate monthly percentile value from daily percentile values

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, percentile

I have a table in `postgres` database with the following representation :

```
date         name    percentile95
2018-09-01    a           0.34
2018-09-02    a           0.41
....
2018-09-29    a           0.74
2018-09-30    a           0.39
2018-10-01    a           0.31
2018-10-02    a           0.24
....
2018-10-30    a           0.64
2018-09-31    a           0.89
```

I have the percentile95 value corresponding to a particular name 'a' on every day. What I want to calculate are the montly percentile values from these daily values, so the result would look like this :

```
date         name    percentile95
2018-09-01    a    {aggreate_percentile from sept}
2018-10-01    a    {aggreate_percentile from oct}
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL?

Edit : According to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535145/402462), it's not possible to calculate aggregate percentiles. So, first of all, is it even possible to calculate monthly percentiles from daily percentiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5d34bc8303c627ad63cb2d201dcbe736)

Using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) and [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

**Query**

```
SELECT
    *, 
    percentile95 / SUM(percentile95) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', "date")) 
        * 100 as percentile_in_month
FROM
    t
```

**Result:**

```
date                  name   percentile95   percentile_in_month
2018-09-01 00:00:00   a      0.34           12.2743682310469
2018-09-02 00:00:00   a      0.41           14.8014440433213
2018-09-29 00:00:00   a      0.74           26.7148014440433
2018-09-30 00:00:00   a      0.39           14.0794223826715
2018-09-30 00:00:00   a      0.89           32.129963898917
2018-10-02 00:00:00   a      0.24           20.1680672268908
2018-10-30 00:00:00   a      0.64           53.781512605042
2018-10-01 00:00:00   a      0.31           26.0504201680672
```

1. `date_trunc` normalizes your dates to the month.
2. The window function groups values (here the truncated dates)
3. The aggregate function `SUM` sums up all values in the window group
4. The summarized values and the origin values are taken for calculating the percent values

Comment: @Jarvis Please do not forget to upvote the helpful answers (not only accepting). This honors the work people did for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `date_part` function to get year and month then do `SUM` in subquery, then self-join on month and year and do some calculation

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   date timestamp,
   name varchar(50),
   percentile95 float
);

insert into T values ('2018-09-01','a',0.34);
insert into T values ('2018-09-02','a',0.41);
insert into T values ('2018-09-29','a',0.74);
insert into T values ('2018-09-30','a',0.39);
insert into T values ('2018-10-01','a',0.31);
insert into T values ('2018-10-02','a',0.24);
insert into T values ('2018-10-30','a',0.64);
insert into T values ('2018-09-30','a',0.89);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
    date,
    t1.name, 
    concat((percentile95 * 100/total ),'%') percentile95
from T t1 JOIN (
  SELECT  
      date_part('year', date) y,
      date_part('month', date) m,
      name,
      sum(percentile95) total
  FROM T 
  group by date_part('year', date),
           date_part('month', date),
           name 
) v 
ON
  v.y = date_part('year', t1.date)
and
  v.m = date_part('month', t1.date)
and
  v.name = t1.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18f7a/19/0)**:

```
|                 date | name |         percentile95 |
|----------------------|------|----------------------|
| 2018-09-01T00:00:00Z |    a | 12.2743682310469318% |
| 2018-09-02T00:00:00Z |    a | 14.8014440433213004% |
| 2018-09-29T00:00:00Z |    a | 26.7148014440433208% |
| 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |    a | 14.0794223826714795% |
| 2018-09-30T00:00:00Z |    a | 32.1299638989169694% |
| 2018-10-02T00:00:00Z |    a | 20.1680672268907557% |
| 2018-10-30T00:00:00Z |    a | 53.7815126050420176% |
| 2018-10-01T00:00:00Z |    a | 26.0504201680672267% |
```

Comment: I have one doubt. According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535145/402462), it says it is not possible to calculate aggregated percentiles. So, is it really possible to calculate percentile from percentiles?

Comment: If you want to get avg from by year and month it is ok http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18f7a/2

Comment: I don't think I want average. I want percentile value for the month. This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1738284/402462) says taking average of percentiles is not correct.